# Skip a String from Replace, if it has any suffix or postfix <VBScript>

Tags: vbscript

I have a one Big File, In which I need to replace one string from the another. 
File is getting Generated from the Jenkins Build and to process that, its using VBscript.

Here is the Deal for me, I can simply replace the string like this,

```
Replace(str_Renamed, "Variables", "Variables_Base", 1, -1, 1)
```

but in the same file "variables" is also there with suffix and postfix, these particular string i need to skip from the replace.

does VBscript has any function which can be useful for above conditions. 
I am also looking for the answers, If I would find anything for it. I will post here.

P.S - I had tried with Regex also, But it didn't worked for me.  as follows

> The special character "^" matches the start of the string.Similarly,
>   the special character "$" matches the end of the string, whereas the
>   pattern "^abc$" only matches the exact string "abc".

https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/vbscript-regexp-objects/#regular-expression-syntax

```
DIM oRE
Set oRE = New RegExp
oRE.Global = True
oRE.Pattern = "^Variables$" 
oRE.Replace("all Varablies value Replaced in FVariablesTemp File", "Variables_Base")
```

it should replace only "Variables" not any other string which has substring as "Variables"

Now, Can anyone update me, how to use regex in VbScript?

Comment: See [VBScript’s Regular Expression Support](https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Comment: You can use the regex as mentioned in above comment. How do you differentiate the one's which you want to replace with the one's which you want to skip. If it is just the space at the start and end of it you can just include it that way in your replace function.

Answer (score 1):

Regex syntax

```
^abc    string starts with "abc"
abc$    string ends with "abc"
```

so when using `^Variables$` you search not for a part but the whole string.

Use instead

```
oRE.Pattern = "\bVariables\b"
```

where `\b` stands for word boundary.

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to replace desired strings to be get replaced.